# LiveBindings or OOP?

Tags: class, delphi, object, tclientdataset, livebindings

I have a question regarding OOP. I'm not new to Delphi, but I learned it by myself, mostly from the internet and didn't learned it the "correct" way. I just started to take a look at OOP some weeks ago. So this is my problem:
I have an own Class called "Session". This class is connected with Edits through Visual LiveBindings. I want to fill my class with data from a TClientDataset (there is a reason why I don't bind the dataset with the edits directly). Now I have 2 ideas:
1. I build another class which implements the Dataset and handles the opening of files and Navigation.
2. I Drag and drop the ClientDataset one my Form and connect it to my class with Livebindings, like this: DataSet <---> Class <---> Edit

I hope you understand my description. So: Which idea is better? I have the feeling that LiveBindings "destroy" the Concept of OOP. On the other hand I don't need to write Code and typecast, because the live bindings do that for me.
So which way would you choose and why? Or has somebody another idea?

I hope you understand what I mean and can help me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With LiveBindings it is perfectly possible to bind to objects instead of datasets.
See: http://www.malcolmgroves.com/blog/?p=1084

In summary: take look at [TAdapterBindSource](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/Tutorial:_Using_TAdapterBindSource_and_the_LiveBindings_Designer) component. It is designed for creating LiveBindings between existing controls and custom objects. In it's onCreateAdapter event you can return a TObjectBindSourceAdapter as aBindSourceAdapter in case you want to bind one specific object, or return a TListBindSourceAdapter for binding list of objects.

LiveBindings and OOP does not bite each other!

Comment: Yes thanks, the Link and your desription helped a lot :)